# Unable to load schema from in https://json.schemastore.org/ in package.json

Tags: javascript, html, json, web, npm

[image]

When i did
nmp init
the package.json file was showing up a problem which is **unable to load schema**.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall nodejs of your project and use npm i --legacy-peer-deps. Then do it again